# How to drag-scroll a overflow:hidden div on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

How would i go around scrolling a div with overflow:hidden property with touch input?

I am developing a board-game in html5/jquery mobile/css and my tiled board is inside of a div with overflow:hidden. I would like to let the user scroll around the board with touch input without scrollbars what so ever. Like "Position:relative; left:0; right:0".

I tried the "Kinect" Dragscroll plugin which does the job top notch, the only problem is that i am not allowed to click on the tiles since its handled as a drag event, any fix for this or a fix for the problem in general?

all help is appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got an answer for this one. SO closing it.

Thank you all.